# Disable button after submit with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, forms, http-post

I am trying to prevent a form being submitted twice. I have implemented a solution that was previously posted, but I cannot make it work. The button is not disabled and the "alert" that I put for debugging is not displayed. Any ideas?

I have this code in the

```
$('#choice').submit(function()
{  
    $('#btnPlus').attr('disabled',true);
    alert('done');
    this.submit();
});
```

And this is the form:

```
<form id="choice" name='form' method="POST" action="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="projId" value="{{proj}}">
    <button type="submit" name="vote" id="btnPlus" value="p{{proj}}"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: try `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are you running your code at the end of the page or in a document ready call? Did you properly include jQuery?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't explain why the "alert" is not displayed.

Comment: if the alert is not being ran, then that function is never getting executed. Make sure you you have all your selectors set up appropriately. I just ran your code exactly in jsfiddle and it ran fine. Maybe you forgot to include jQuery?

Comment: I have `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the head right before my code. Should I put my code somewhere else perhaps?

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: try this instead `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` It is better to use specified versions of CDN's when including code so that when they are updated you don't have something break by accident. Just a good practice to preserve some robustness. Also in newer versions of HTML you don't have to specify `type="text/javascript"` which is a nice space saver, doesn't make a huge difference though

Comment: No errors are shown on the console

Comment: I find that hard to believe. Recreate your issue in a stack snippet in your question or a jsFiddle because we cannot

Comment: @j08691 https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=aPoa07QFAP

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in that fiddle. Checking the console for errors would've shown you that. And adding it shows the alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `e.preventDefault()` to stop the submit first then do what you want and trigger the submit after taht using `this.submit();`, since as written now the code you've in submit function will not execute and the page will be submited when you click :

```
$('#choice').submit(function(e)
{  
    //Stop submit
    e.preventDefault(); 

    //Do what you want
    $('#btnPlus').attr('disabled',true);
    alert('done');

    //Submit
    this.submit();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But this doesn't explain why the alert he has isn't being displayed

Comment: Updated my answer @j08691 (trying to explain)

Comment: alerts are blocking though and would appear prior to the form submitting

Comment: Seems that it is totally ignoring the $('#choice').submit(). Can it be because I am using <button> instead of <input>?

Comment: Have you tried submit input ? (button should work fine also https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/244/)

Comment: @Arturo - Why did you accept this answer? How did it solve your problem?

Comment: seems that in my server it was blocking jQuery but I downloaded the JS and works well. After solving this, I implemented Zakaria's solution and works well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `prop` instead of the `attr` function:

```
<script>
  $('#choice').submit(function()
  {  
      $('#btnPlus').prop('disabled',true);
      alert('done');
      this.submit();
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait I see the error and we are all going to feel a bit silly,

```
<form id="choice" name='form' method="POST" action="/">
  <input type="hidden" name="projId" value="{{proj}}">
  <input type="submit" name="vote" id="btnPlus" value="p{{proj}}">
</form>
```

`<button>` is not a valid HTML element for submitting forms, as far as I know. If you can use `<button>` as a submit then that is news to me as everything I have learned to date always says to use `<input type="submit">` when dealing with form fields.

EDIT: Didn't realize someone came to the same conclusion in the comments above prior to my own realization

Comment: A button with the type submit is fine for submitting a form. In fact, the submit type is the default for a button.

Answer (score 0):

Here - Jquery and BOOTSTRAP 4

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        //------------------------- begin ------------------------- 
        //add class "clicked" for the clicked button
        $('button').on('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        });
        //desable clicked submit button after first click - prevent double click
        $('form').submit(function(e){  
            e.preventDefault(); //Stop submit
            $(document).find('.clicked').attr('disabled',true); //disable button
            $(document).find('.clicked').html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>'); //change text button for load spinner
            this.submit(); //Submit
        }); 
        //-------------------------- end -------------------------- 
        });
```